# Global variable overridden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a web application with two controllers abc_controller.rb and xyz_controller.rb. Both have the same variable with different content:

```
$pqrs = ["1", "2"] // in one controller, abc
$pqrs = ["3", "4"] // in another controller, xyz
```

I am opening a webpage with abc in url, which calls abc_controller.rb. When I print the value of `$pqrs` inside `abc_controller`, it outputs`["3", "4"]` instead of `["1", "2"]`.

Any idea what can be the reason for this?

Comment: Because it's shared globally across your Rails application when Rails starts autoloading your app directory.

Comment: Depending on were you do the setting, it could be simply the order of the loads as @RobNice mentions.  I think it would be better to describe what problem you are trying to solve by even sharing state across controllers and why you think you need to use a global variable

Comment: PSA: **DO NOT USE GLOBAL VARIABLES**. They're a ton of trouble and completely inappropriate in this case. Use instance variables like `@pqrs`. A variable like `$pqrs` is global across *all classes, all instances* and requires careful coordination between all bits of code accessing it. Instance variables do not do this.

Comment: What are the regexes at the end of the lines?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you explain what kind of answer you are looking for, other than "because it's a **global** variable"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are using is a global variable. A global variable starts with a `$` and is available across your entire application. If you change the variable anywhere in your application, it will be changed everywhere. Depending on what you are trying to do, you can either use a class variable (still not great, but better than a global variable) by using `@@` or a class instance variable by using a `@`.

A class variable is similar to a global variable, but only the class and its subclasses have access to it. That means any changes to the class variable by a subclass changes the variable in the parent class.

A class instance variable is only available to the class that creates the variable. You can create the same class instance variable in a subclass or other classes and you won't have a clash of instance variable names.

You can read more about class variables and class instance variables here:
[Class Variables and Class Instance Variables](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/faq/8/)